# MySQL триггеры - добавить к значению в INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

Можно ли в триггере

```
BEGIN

insert into stat (`hash`, `flushtime`) values (new.hash, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());

END
```

cделать для `new.hash` добавить значение через разделитель '|' DAY(CURDATE()) ?
Через CONCAT может?

Т.е нужно чтобы получилось('dsfh3sddf3|6') , не могу понять как на SQL это написать , типа такого: 'new.hash|DAY(CURDATE())' .

Comment: `CONCAT(new.hash, " |", day(now()))`

Comment: Если это триггер на таблице `stat` - то он ошибочный и не будет создан.

Comment: Нет , таблица другая

Comment: @splash58 Какой смысл в `day(now())`, есть же CURRENT_DATE.

Comment: Тогда **splash58** дал ответ. Только два вопроса. Первый- зачем BEGIN-END, если весь триггер состоит из одного запроса? Второй - зачем явно присваивать flushtime, если есть DEFAULT CURRRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Про BEGIN END поправил - спасибо.  А flushtime можно и CURRRENT_TIMESTAMP , но потом его нужно будет форматировать в UNIX TIME при выборке данных . Как эффективнее чтобы меньше нагрузки на базу?

Comment: @Akina current_date() => 20210807